# What ARM architectures does LLVM support?

Tags: architecture, arm, llvm

I work on software written in C that runs on a variety of ARM processors with different architectures (ARMv5, ARMv6 mostly). We currently compile our code with a few different versions of RVDS, but we are looking at compiling some code with LLVM in order to add some custom instrumentation.

I know LLVM has ARM and Thumb targets, but what architectures does it support, specifically? Will LLVM generated code work on ARMv5? What limitations should I be aware of?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Their [source code](http://www.llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/trunk/lib/Target/ARM/ARM.td) lists the following archs:

```
// ARM architectures.
def ArchV4T     : SubtargetFeature<"v4t",  "ARMArchVersion", "V4T",  "ARM v4T">;
def ArchV5T     : SubtargetFeature<"v5t",  "ARMArchVersion", "V5T",  "ARM v5T">;
def ArchV5TE    : SubtargetFeature<"v5te", "ARMArchVersion", "V5TE", "ARM v5TE, v5TEj, v5TExp">;
def ArchV6      : SubtargetFeature<"v6",   "ARMArchVersion", "V6",   "ARM v6">;
def ArchV6M     : SubtargetFeature<"v6m",  "ARMArchVersion", "V6M",  "ARM v6m",  [FeatureNoARM, FeatureDB]>;
def ArchV6T2    : SubtargetFeature<"v6t2", "ARMArchVersion", "V6T2", "ARM v6t2", [FeatureThumb2]>;
def ArchV7A     : SubtargetFeature<"v7a",  "ARMArchVersion", "V7A",  "ARM v7A",  [FeatureThumb2, FeatureNEON, FeatureDB]>;
def ArchV7M     : SubtargetFeature<"v7m",  "ARMArchVersion", "V7M",  "ARM v7M",  [FeatureThumb2, FeatureNoARM, FeatureDB, FeatureHWDiv]>;
```

Comment: It's good to have an authoritative list like this. It's hard to know what level of stability each architecture has, though.

Comment: While these are the arches the LLVM backend knows about, it is best tested on v5te, v6 and v7a. v5te is a config on the LLVM Buildbot http://google1.osuosl.org:8011/ and v6 and v7a are both tested as arm-apple-darwin (iOS) on Apple's "smooshlab" Buildbot.

Comment: It links to trunk, but from which version was this list taken?

Comment: @RedX: It should have been taken at some point between 2.8 and 2.9. Looking at the 2.8 release, it looks like that's pretty accurate. http://www.llvm.org/svn/llvm-project/llvm/tags/RELEASE_28/lib/Target/ARM/ARM.td

Comment: The code generated by llvm 3.4 for armv4t is definitely not interworking aware, which is required by EABI. llvm generated pushes `lr` and pops it back into `pc`. However that is basically forbidden if interworking is required as a `pop pc` does not switch between ARM and Thumb mode on armv4t. A function must return to its caller via the `bx` instruction on armv4t. http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=16857

Comment: @Sven: This entire answer is incredibly out of date (I wrote it 4 years ago). As I mention in the previous comment, this snippet was taken back in 2.8. In addition to the current source code link, users would probably want to look at the AArch64 arch as well.

Answer (score 1):

I have run llvm generated code on ARMv4, and ARMv6 definitely.  I have some ARMv5 platforms but dont remember if I tried it there.  I would assume the output of a generic -march=arm would give least common denominator (ARMv4) code, which means it will run on ARMv5.  This was all embedded, no operating system type work mind you, I have not used llvm to create arm linux binaries or anything like that.